# UnimplementedFeatureError: Encoding type "struct BiddingContract.Bidder memory" not yet implemented

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract, struct, truffle-compile

The code is broken with the new upgrade v0.5, 
 using 
  Truffle v5.0.1 (core: 5.0.1)

```
struct Bidder {
    address bidders_address;
    uint productId;
    uint bidValue;
}

struct Product {
    uint productId;
    uint bidStartPrice;
    uint32 bidStartTime;
    Bidder latestBid;
    string productName;
    bool isAvailable;
    uint32 bidSession;

}
```

And mapping as

`mapping(uint => Product)  product;`

removed the public getter venerability but still, the error is coming.

This is my full code :

```
    pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

    import "./AucSters.sol";
    import "../libraries/SafeMath.sol";

    contract BiddingContract {

    using SafeMath for uint; 

    address admin;
    AucSters public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    //structs
    struct Seller {
        uint256 sellerId;
        string sellerName;
        bool isValidSeller;
    }
    struct Bidder {
        address bidders_address;
        uint productId;
        uint bidValue;
    }
    struct Product {
        uint productId;
        uint bidStartPrice;
        uint32 bidStartTime;
        Bidder latestBid;
        string productName;
        bool isAvailable;
        uint32 bidSession;

    }

    mapping(address => Seller) registeredSeller;
    mapping(uint => address) public productIdToOwner;
    mapping(address => uint) public productCount;
    mapping(uint => Product) product;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint => uint)) public latestBidStore;

    //ARRAYS
    address[] public regSellers;
    Product[] public productsForSale;
    address[] public bidders;


    constructor(AucSters _tokenContract, uint _tokenPrice) public {
        //Assign an admin
        admin = msg.sender;

        // token Contract 
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;

        //Token price
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
   }


}
```

Comment: The code you shared so far compiles fine for me. Could you share the code that has the error?

Comment: yeah sure , done

Comment: I removed `public` from the declaration of `product`, I deleted all the lines that reference the `AucSters` contract (which you didn't provide a definition for). I converted the safe math references to normal math operations. After that, the code compiled fine.

Comment: If you want more help, please provide a _self-contained_ piece of code (something that can just be copy/pasted, without references to files you didn't provide) that exhibits the problem. Preferably, delete all the code that isn't necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: updated the code in question no functions , still not working for me

Comment: The code in the question still refers to AucSters and SafeMath without providing code for either. It would also help to know what Solidity version you're using. Your  pragma allows a lot of different versions.

Comment: Also, what line of code gives you that error?

Comment: @smarx, I got it working , It was the array of Products making the mess out there .  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I got the issue solved !

The array declares productsForSale also gives a by default getter as it is public, remove `public` and it will work

```
Product[] public productsForSale;
```

replace it by

```
 Product[] productsForSale;
```

Comment: In case it helps, that's because it contains a `struct` (`Bidder`) and the "free" getter requested with `public` doesn't support that.